# Update table every time my database is changed [HTMX][Dajngo-tables2]

Tags: django, django-tables2, htmx

I want to Update table every time my database is changed, without refreshing. Also, I want to keep my query parameters from a search when the update happens

What I done so far is use hx-get to retrieve my table from another template and view to get me the updated table.

However, I don't know where to start to trigger a update when the database is changed

Views.py

```
def display_view(request):
    myFilter = ParticipantFilter(request.GET, queryset=Participant.objects.all())
    table = ParticipantTable(myFilter.qs)
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page=10)
    return render(request, 'display.html', {'table': table,'myFilter': myFilter})

def data_only_view(request):
    myFilter = ParticipantFilter(request.GET, queryset=Participant.objects.all())
    table = ParticipantTable(myFilter.qs)
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page=10)
    return render(request, 'updatedDisplay.html', {'table': table})
```

display.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form method="get">
    {{ myFilter.form }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>


<div id="table-results" hx-get="/updatedDisplay" hx-include = "[name='first_name']">
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<table class="table">
  {% render_table table %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
</div>
```

updateDisplay.html

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<table class="table">
  {% render_table table %}
</table>
```

Comment: Have you considered a Django Signal that gets triggered whenever a Participant obj is saved? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/

Answer (score 1):

Without django channels you can only use pooling. I see you used hx-include for input with name 'first_name' i believe you can include full form. Additionaly you can point your form to make htmx request instead of reloading page:

```
<form hx-get="/updatedDisplay" id="my_form" hx-target="#table-results">
    {{ myFilter.form }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>

<div id="table-results" hx-get="/updatedDisplay" hx-include="#my_form" hx-trigger="every 5s">
#innerHTML
</div>
```

this way your table will be updated every 5 seconds.